# Нужно переделать код так, чтобы вводилась матрица из файла

Tags: c++

Написал код, но в итоге сказали переделать так, чтобы считывались слова из файла, как матрица и каждая строка должна быть отсортирована по увеличению количества символов (уже сделал). Я просто не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы из файла считывалось это. Очень буду благодарен за помощь.

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "Enter string:" << endl;
    getline(cin, s);
    vector<string> v;
    istringstream iss(s);

    string word;
    while (iss >> word) {
        v.push_back(word);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<v.size() - 1;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<v.size() - 1;j++)
           if(v[j].length()>v[j+1].length())
                swap(v[j], v[j+1]);

    cout << "Result:" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать freopen

```
freopen(file_name, "r", stdin);
```

Добавьте его в начало `int main` и всё, что должно было читаться из стандартного потока, пойдёт из файла

Вот переделанный под матрицу код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

    string s;
    cout << "Enter string:" << endl;
    getline(cin, s);

    vector<vector<char> > v;

    istringstream iss(s);

    string word;
    int i = 0;

    while (iss >> word) {
        v.push_back(vector<char>(0));

        for (char c : word) 
        {
            v[i].push_back(c);
        }
        i++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<v.size() - 1;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<v.size() - 1;j++)
            if(v[j].size()>v[j+1].size())
                swap(v[j], v[j+1]);

    cout << "Result:" << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            cout << v[i][j];
        }
        cout << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А как сделать саму матрицу ?

Comment: vector<vector <char> > v;
Но ввод и вывод должны стать посимвольными